# Python Pillow/PIL color shifting issue. In GIF

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

CODE: **https://gist.github.com/jksfsfjk23h4/d95df9778ce6769873d584349d4f24a3**

```
animated_gif = Image.open("trippy.gif")

#getting size
x_qr = animated_gif.size[0]
y_qr = animated_gif.size[1]

img__ = Image.new('RGBA', (x_qr, y_qr), (0, 0, 0, 0))
resized_picture_1 = qrAdder(img__,"http://ke")

frames = []
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(animated_gif):
    frame = frame.copy()
    frame.convert('RGBA')
    # resized_picture_1 = qrAdde    r(frame,"http://ke")
    frame.paste(resized_picture_1, (0,0),resized_picture_1)
    frame.convert('RGB')
    frames.append(frame)

frames[0].save('wowi.gif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:])
```

my gifs are color shifting after I add an other PNG

The gif output

[image: Gif output]

The QR code (Has no background)

[image: QR code]

Answer (score 0):

The GIF format represents color using an 8-bit palette ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Palettes)). The maximum number of distinct colors in a GIF frame is 256. One palette entry is often spent on "clear" for animation, reducing to 255 distinct colors. When you added the PNG image, PIL converted it to use the closest available colors in the palette, but apparently nothing in the palette was that close.

To fix the colors, try this:

1. Convert the base image to RGB (`.convert('RGB')`).
2. Add the PNG.
3. Convert back to palette mode (`.convert('P')`).

That way, PIL will generate a new palette that better approximates all colors in the combined image.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jksfsfjk23h4/d95df9778ce6769873d584349d4f24a3